# What Is the Name of an Object Created in a WITH Clause in a Materialized View in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, naming, materialized-views

I am having a hard time searching through PostgreSQL documentation to find the right terminology to associate with table/view creation within the `WITH` clause of a `MATERIALIZED VIEW`.

For the following matview (the `AS WITH` clause is the point of focus) :

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_big_fat_payments_matview AS WITH
  some_structure_representing_records_paid AS
    (
      SELECT polymorphic_fk_id, polymorphic_fk_type, amount, transaction_time
      FROM my_big_fat_billing_table
      WHERE some_condition = 'A First Condition'
        AND some_other_condition IS NOT NULL
   ),
  some_structure_representing_records_discounted AS
    (
      SELECT polymorphic_fk_id, polymorphic_fk_type, amount, transaction_time
      FROM my_big_fat_billing_table
      WHERE some_condition = 'A Second Condition'
        AND some_other_condition IS NOT NULL
   ),
  some_structure_representing_records_misc AS
    (
      SELECT polymorphic_fk_id, polymorphic_fk_type, amount, transaction_time
      FROM my_big_fat_billing_table
      WHERE some_condition = 'A Threeved Condition'
        AND some_other_condition IS NOT NULL
   )
SELECT
  thetable.column_a  AS column_a,
  thetable.column_x  AS column_x,
  thetable.amount    AS amount,
  secondtable.amount AS second_amount,
  thirdtable.amount  AS third_amount,
  fourthtable.amount AS fourth_amount
FROM my_big_fat_billing_table AS thetable
LEFT JOIN some_structure_representing_records_paid AS secondtable
  ON thetable.polymorphic_fk_id = secondtable.polymorphic_fk_id
LEFT JOIN some_structure_representing_records_discounted AS thirdtable
  ON thetable.polymorphic_fk_id = thirdtable.polymorphic_fk_id
LEFT JOIN some_structure_representing_records_misc AS fourthtable
  ON thetable.polymorphic_fk_id = fourthtable.polymorphic_fk_id
WHERE thetable.type = 'Some Type'
```

What is the name for the `some_structure_representing_records_paid`, `some_structure_representing_records_discounted`, and `some_structure_representing_records_misc` objects in the query? Are they views? I have been casually referring to them as "sub-views" of the matview, but I cant seem to find my way into deeper documentation of the `WITH` clause of this matview to determine if that sort of jargon is appropriate. If they are not views, what are they? Would they be synonyms? Are they temporary tables that only exist for the selection of data and creation of the matview?

*Note: my matview is way more complicated than this, so I am not asking for a critique on structure/format/use/etc.*

Comment: These are CTE's, or Common Table Expressions.  They can be used as part of any query (not just a view).

Comment: Thanks sir, that made web searching for my answer very easy (not sure why this information is not present on the `WITH` clause documentation linked from the `MATERIALIZED VIEW` documentation). In any event, @AaronLS if you post that as an answer with a link to this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html and quote that first line mentioning a "temporary table", I will accept as an answer :).

Comment: @Todd that is because CTEs have nothing to do with VIEWS per se.

Comment: @KamilG. thank you for your edit, but what you have changed the title to no longer asks the same question as I am asking. I am not asking generally what the `WITH` clause is, but the name of the objects created in my particular subqueries. Asking about the entire `WITH` clause would return far too generalized of an answer.

Comment: @Todd thanks for correction :-) We are here to help the future readers. Though, they are basically "WITH Queries" as stated in documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Credit goes to @AaronLS for the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884960/what-is-the-name-of-an-object-created-in-a-with-clause-in-a-materialized-view-in/39084241#comment65130574_38884960):*

The "temp table" created with a `WITH` clause of the `MATERIALIZED VIEW` is known as a "Common Table Expression" or a CTE.

Full documentation can be found here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html